# Multiple Select Statement in MYSQL Query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a a mysql table contaning date wise sale of products on different marketplaces .

```
Date   Marketplace   Sale 
1      flipkart       1000
1      flipkart       500
1      amazon          200
1      amazon         1500
1      amazon          700
2      myntra          500
2      flipkart       1000
```

I want a single mysql statement that gives me date wise gross sale of different marketplaces (amazon,flipkart etc) for a month like in this case
on

1st of month flipkart gross sale is 1500 (1000+500) , amazon gross sale 2400 (1500+700+200)

I have this query :

```
SELECT  date, (Select sum(gross_sale) from sku where marketplace='flipkart') as flipkart, (Select sum(gross_sale) from sku where marketplace='Myntra') as myntra, sum(gross_sale) as countdate FROM sku WHERE   date >= '2017-11-01' AND
        date   <= '2017-11-30' GROUP BY date ORDER BY date ASC limit 30 ;
```

but the select subquery doesn't give me date wise distribution , instead the total gross sale of month . how to solve that problem . Please help. thanks in advance.

Comment: We appreciate Sample data and desired output.

Comment: `select Date, Marketplace, sum(Sale)  from yourtable group by Date, Marketplace`

Comment: Have you tried it with [Sum](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-sum/)? Second result in Google. You really should do some more research, before you ask a question here.

Comment: amazon gross sale 2700 (1500+700+500) ?? As per your sample data it should be Amazon gross sale 2400 (200+1500+700)

Comment: Check the answer at bottom with a link to the sqlfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT 
    sk.date,
    sum(sk1.sale) as flipkart_sum_sale,
    sum(sk2.sale) as amanzon_sum_sale
FROM
    sku sk
        LEFT JOIN
    sku sk1 ON sk.id = sk1.id
        AND sk1.marketplace = 'flipkart'
        LEFT JOIN
    sku sk2 ON sk.id = sk2.id
        AND sk2.marketplace = 'amazon'
GROUP BY sk.date;
```

Comment: Thanks. It Worked !

Comment: Can You also let me know how do i use where clause in this for dates specified in question.

Comment: Please try now:SELECT 
    sk.date,
    sum(sk1.sale) as flipkart_sum_sale,
    sum(sk2.sale) as amanzon_sum_sale
FROM
    sku sk
        LEFT JOIN
    sku sk1 ON sk.id = sk1.id
        AND sk1.marketplace = 'flipkart'
        LEFT JOIN
    sku sk2 ON sk.id = sk2.id
        AND sk2.marketplace = 'amazon'
WHERE   (sk1.date >= '2017-11-01' AND
        sk1.date   <= '2017-11-30') OR (sk2.date >= '2017-11-01' AND
        sk2.date   <= '2017-11-30')
GROUP BY sk.date;

Answer (score 2):

Mysql give you `sum()` and group by function for the task. You can retrieve the required result by following query

`select Date, Marketplace, sum(Sale) from table group by Date, Marketplace`

`sum()` will be sum all the prices of same marketplace with the help of `group by`

**After your comment**

If you don't want to use loop and you need single result with query, then you just need `where` clause

`select Date, Marketplace, sum(Sale) from table where Marketplace = 'flipkart'`

Comment: Thanks for help, but i want sum(sale) as different variable for different marketplace like "select date, sum(flipkart_sale), sum (amazon_sale), from table group by date"

Comment: @NishankMagoo Kindly check now

Comment: @Mr.Developer but this will run for only one marketplace. I want single query for all marketplace for one month.

SELECT  date, sum(gross sale of flipkart) as flipkart, sum(gross_sale of amazon), sum (gross_sale of myntra)  FROM sku WHERE date >= '2017-11-01' AND
        date   <= '2017-11-30' GROUP BY date,marketplace ORDER BY date ASC limit 30

Comment: Do i have to use union here if i want multiple marketplaces .

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT Date,Marketplace, SUM(Sale) 
FROM tab111 where date =1
Group By Marketplace
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried doing a union:

```
select date,marketplace,sum(sales) from yourtable where marketplace='flipkart'

union

select date,marketplace,sum(sales) from yourtable where marketplace='amazon'
```

Here's the [**sqlfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eda5e1/2)

Answer (score 0):

```
select Date,Marketplace, sum(Sale) from table group by Marketplace;
```